# sudo asks for password

Tags: server, sudo

I have a few virtual machines from Amazon Lightsail and Linode all running Ubuntu 22.04.

With Amazon, by default, the root login is disabled, public-key authentication is enabled and default user is `ubuntu`.

With Linode, there's no default user and root login with password is enabled.

So on Linode I disable root login, create `ubuntu` user, disable password-login, enable public-key login and add `ubuntu` to `sudo` group.

So far everything works fine.

However, on Linode `sudo` command asks for password of `ubuntu` user but on Amazon doesn't.

So I run `sudo visudo` on both Amazon and Linode and notice that the content is **exactly** the same but on Amazon `sudo` doesn't ask for password while on Linode it does:

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

What else I have to check/change to stop `sudo` from asking for password?